How to create new columns with conditional values based on grouped column data in R?
I have a data frame in R, and I need to create two new columns based on conditions applied to existing columns. Here’s the data frame:
  data <- data.frame (
    ID = c(rep(91, 4), rep(92, 5), rep(95, 3), rep(90, 4)),
    time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4),
    TT = c(rep(32, 4), rep(37, 5), rep(10, 3), rep(20, 4)),
    PT = c(245, 345, 100, 273, 270, 340, 240, 170, 80, 33, 230, 50, 85, 
    100, 200, 200))

The PT column is a numeric variable for each ID at different time points. I want to create two new columns, CT and mTT, with the following rules:
CT column: For each row, CT should be the minimum of PT and 180. However, if the last PT value for an ID (ordered by time) is less than 180, then CT for that row should be set to 180.
mTT column: Normally, mTT should be equal to TT. But if the last PT value for each ID is less than 180, then mTT for that row should be TT + (180 - PT).
The desired output is as follows:
result<- data.frame(
         ID = c(rep(91, 4), rep(92, 5), rep(95, 3), rep(90, 4)),
         time= c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4),
         TT = c(rep(32, 4), rep(37, 5), rep(10, 3), rep(20, 4)),
         PT = c(245, 345, 100, 273, 270, 340, 240, 170, 80, 33, 230, 50, 
         85, 100, 200, 200),
         CT =c(180,180,100,180,180,180,180,170,180,33,180,180,85,100,
         180,180),
         mTT= c(rep(32, 4), rep(37, 4),137, rep(10, 2),140, rep(20, 4)))

How can I implement this logic in R, ideally using dplyr?"

library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(time_n=max(time), .by=ID) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(CT=ifelse(time==time_n & PT<180, 180, min(180, PT)),
         mTT=ifelse(time==time_n & PT<180, TT + (180 - PT), TT)) %>%
  select(-time_n) %>%
    ungroup()

Gives
# A tibble: 16 × 6
      ID  time    TT    PT    CT   mTT
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1    91     1    32   245   180    32
 2    91     2    32   345   180    32
 3    91     3    32   100   100    32
 4    91     4    32   273   180    32
 5    92     1    37   270   180    37
 6    92     2    37   340   180    37
 7    92     3    37   240   180    37
 8    92     4    37   170   170    37
 9    92     5    37    80   180   137
10    95     1    10    33    33    10
11    95     2    10   230   180    10
12    95     3    10    50   180   140
13    90     1    20    85    85    20
14    90     2    20   100   100    20
15    90     3    20   200   180    20
16    90     4    20   200   180    20

Edit:
data %>%
  mutate(time_n=max(time), .by=ID) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(CT=ifelse(time==time_n & PT<180, 180, min(180, PT)),
         mTT=ifelse(time==time_n & PT<180, TT + (180 - PT), TT)) %>%
  select(-time_n) %>%
  ungroup() |>
  mutate(mTT=case_when(ID==92~137,
                       ID==95~140,
                       .default=mTT))

Gives:
# A tibble: 16 x 6
      ID  time    TT    PT    CT   mTT
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1    91     1    32   245   180    32
 2    91     2    32   345   180    32
 3    91     3    32   100   100    32
 4    91     4    32   273   180    32
 5    92     1    37   270   180   137
 6    92     2    37   340   180   137
 7    92     3    37   240   180   137
 8    92     4    37   170   170   137
 9    92     5    37    80   180   137
10    95     1    10    33    33   140
11    95     2    10   230   180   140
12    95     3    10    50   180   140
13    90     1    20    85    85    20
14    90     2    20   100   100    20
15    90     3    20   200   180    20
16    90     4    20   200   180    20


Thank you, this is perfect! I'd like to update all mTT values for a specific ID with the maximum calculated value-  all 5 mTT values for ID = 92 to be set to 137, and all 3 mTT values for ID = 95 to be set to 140- Is it possible to implement this within the same code chunk?

For that, you can use case_when - see my edit.

Thanks. I think I didn't phrase my question correctly! In the actual data there are hundreds for whom the mTT should be changed to their maximum value. Actually everyone whose last PT is less than 180, all their mTT should increase by 180-PT.

If there are many of them (hundreds), it won't be feasible to specify them one by one.

It changes the last mTT for each ID not all.

I'm really sorry but I don't understand what you want. :( Could you edit your question, and please show the desired output for the example data provided. Thanks!

by adding %>%  arrange(ID,time) %>%   group_by(ID) %>%   mutate(mTT= ail(mTT,1)) %>%   ungroup()  at the end, mTT will be set to maximum for all and I don't need to do it  individually.

Here is a dplyr approach using the base R parallel minima and maxima functions:

pmax() and pmin() take one or more vectors as arguments, recycle them to common length and return a single vector giving the ‘parallel’ maxima (or minima) of the argument vectors.

library(dplyr)
out <- data |>
    mutate(
        last_PT_low = time == max(time) & last(PT) < 180,
        CT = if_else(last_PT_low, pmax(PT, 180), pmin(PT, 180)),
        mTT = if_else(last_PT_low, TT + (180 - PT), TT),
        .by = ID
    ) |>
    select(-last_PT_low)
#    ID time TT  PT  CT mTT
# 1  91    1 32 245 180  32
# 2  91    2 32 345 180  32
# 3  91    3 32 100 100  32
# 4  91    4 32 273 180  32
# 5  92    1 37 270 180  37
# 6  92    2 37 340 180  37
# 7  92    3 37 240 180  37
# 8  92    4 37 170 170  37
# 9  92    5 37  80 180 137
# 10 95    1 10  33  33  10
# 11 95    2 10 230 180  10
# 12 95    3 10  50 180 140
# 13 90    1 20  85  85  20
# 14 90    2 20 100 100  20
# 15 90    3 20 200 180  20
# 16 90    4 20 200 180  20

identical(out, result) # TRUE

With a data frame of this size it will make no difference, but if your data frame is large this should be noticeably faster than rowwise() operations as it operates on the entire data frame rather than splitting it into rows, computing a summary and joining it back together.

Thank you. If I want increase all mTT's for those whose last PT is less than 180 by 180-PT,- so for example all mTT for ID=92 will be 137- is it possible to implement it in the same chunk of codes?

Borrowing the convincing logic from SamR's answer (please comment if you do not agree), I demonstrate a classical split-*apply-combine approach in base R.
I migth add in another avoiding ifelse() on Sunday.
out = 
  split(df0, factor(f <- df0$ID, levels = unique(f))) |>
  lapply(within, {
    i = time == max(time) & tail(PT, 1) < 180
    mTT = ifelse(i, TT + (180 - PT), TT)
    CT = ifelse(i, pmax(PT, 180), pmin(PT, 180))
    rm(i)
  }) |>
  do.call(what="rbind") |> `row.names<-`(NULL)

giving
> identical(out, result)
[1] TRUE

Notice that I renamed the input data to df0.

Appendix
I use the wrapper
unlist2df = \(l) do.call("rbind", l) |> `row.names<-`(NULL)

If this is not fast enough, I do collapse::unlist2d().
